# Modal view shifting when UISearchBar becomes first responder in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

In my app I am showing a modal view with a search bar. I set becomeFirstResponder in viewDidAppear on the modal view controller. This works fine in portrait view, the modal view and keyboard pop up from the bottom.

When I do this in landscape orientation the modal view appears normal but as the keyboard is shown the view shifts left or right depending on which way the top of the iPad is facing. The modal view seems to think it is still in portrait orientation. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Did you ever figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite positive what the root of this problem is, but I fixed it in my case by setting the modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationPageSheet instead of UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

```
myVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```

Comment: This didn't fix my issue.

Comment: This fixes the issue but the modal view ends up with a bigger frame.
If you want to keep the UIModalPresentationFormSheet style frame this won't work.